# How does the first part of "Intimidating Presence" work?

Tags: star-wars-the-old-republic

In the Juggernaut Tank Tree, there is a skill called "Intimidating Presence".

Within this skill, there is a part that confuses me, which I highlighted:

[image: Sreenshot of "Intimidating Presence"]

So how does this exactly work? I have actually never seen it in action. I often Force Charge into enemies, get kicked back while doing so and Force Charge never finished it's cooldown. So what disruptions trigger this chance? If it where not for the second part with Saber Reflect, I would have gotten rid of it already.

Comment: The cooldown finish on your interrupt should work after every use of force leap/charge. If you have any friends ingame, ask them to try it. You may have stumbled upon a bug. You said you are getting knocked back when charging into enemies? Does this happen every time or is this the standard knockback that some higher lvl mobs have? Does the cooldown finish never occur at all or does sometimes? Perhaps being knocked back is happening before the system considers the charge/leap to be complete and is therefore not registering correct for the interrupt cooldown to be finished.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It isn't that you being disrupted will reset the cool down on Force Charge. It is that using Force Charge will reset the cool down on your [Disruption](http://www.torhead.com/ability/gd4jbeQ/disruption) ability.

Comment: Okay that explains it. Must be the wording. Still useless, since Disruption has a really low CD. Anyway, thanks for answering.

Comment: @Assylum: Can be good against players. Remember that Push resets force charge. Sorcerer casts and you Charge which interrupts. He casts again so you Disrupt. He casts again so you Push which interrupts. He casts so Charge. Then you can Disrupt... Good thing sorcerers get Polarity Shift.